# how to create trackbar in opencv with java API

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

I want to create a trackbar\sliderbar using Opencv2411 with Java API. I did not find any class in opencv Java docs that does so.

How can I create trackbar in opencv with Java API??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV Java api does not allow you to handle any of the GUI stuff, so no you cannot create a trackbar using OpenCV Java

What you can do though is use [swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) and jsliders

```
JSlider example slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, MIN, MAX, DEFAULT);
```